# ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Angular 6 - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I'm trying to do heatmap work with Googlemaps with Typescript and Angular 6. There are 400,000 records in the data transmission. I'm getting this error in Chrome.

[image: console error]

WHY ?